# forms in Smarty

Tags: php, forms, smarty

I'm looking for some help creating a very simple form in a Smarty template but I'm not familiar with how to do this.

The form calculates how many litres of a product a customer needs to cover X square metres.

```
<form action="/calc.php" method="post">
<h4>How much area would you like to cover?</h4>
<input type="number" name="area" min="1">&nbsp;m<sup>2</sup><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

In the calc.php file I calculate the correct number of litres required.

```
$area = $_POST['area'];
$coverage = $area/3.5;
$litres = number_format($coverage/5,2);
```

could someone tell me how I pass the values from the php file back to the template?

Is there a better way I should be doing this?

**Update:**
template script is now:

```
<form action="/calc.php" method="post">
<h4>How much area would you like to cover?</h4>
<input type="number" name="area" min="1">&nbsp;m<sup>2</sup><br>
<input type="submit" style="margin-top:5px;">
</form>

<p>You require {$litres_selected} Litres to cover an area of {$target_area} m<sup>2</sup></p>
```

php script is now:

```
<?php

$area = $_POST['area'];
$coverage = $area/3.5;
$litres = number_format($coverage/5,2);

$smarty_object->assign(array('litres_selected' => $litres));
$smarty_object->assign(array('target_area' => $area));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> could someone tell me how I pass the values from the php file back to
>   the template?

You can send PHP variables to smarty like this:

```
$smarty_object->assign(array('litres_selected' => $litres));
```

Then in smarty template you can retrieve these variables easily like this:

```
{$litres_selected}
```

Comment: Great thanks. I've updated my script, please see the updated section I added to my original post. is this correct? it's not showing the values when I click submit on the form.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Maybe you can set any dummy value instead of your variable to test them. $smarty_object->assign(array('litres_selected' => '5'));